# Where can i put an onClickListener in my Fragment?

Tags: android

In my app I use some Fragments with some Buttons that help to navigate through different contents.
The layout I built works perfectly, but now i want to make the links for the Buttons.

MY BUTTON ID IS: buttonSP

Where can I add the onClickListener in my code snippet to open a new Activity named: Lista_Smartphone?

**FragmentWithOneImage.java**

```
public class FragmentWithOneImage extends Fragment {
private String title;
private int image;


public static FragmentWithOneImage newInstance(String title, int resImage) {
    FragmentWithOneImage fragment = new FragmentWithOneImage();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("image", resImage);
    args.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    image = getArguments().getInt("image", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("title");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_img, container, false);
    TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
    tvLabel.setText(title);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMain);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it on the onCreateView() method. it is equivalent of onCreate() of activity class

Answer (score 0):

in **onCreateView()** method add below code

```
Context con = getActivity();
Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSP);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Move to Lista_Smartphone from Current fragment
                startActivity(new Intent(con, Lista_Smartphone.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Variable 'con' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: solved the 'con' there is an error saying: unreacheable statement in this line: Button buttonSP = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSP);

Answer (score 0):

Use `onActivityCreated()` method  , some times finding views in `onCreateView()` takes time and in those cases null pointer exception may arise.

```
   public class FragmentWithOneImage  extends Fragment {


    TextView tvLabel;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;

    public static FragmentWithOneImage newInstance(String title, int resImage) {
        FragmentWithOneImage fragment = new FragmentWithOneImage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("image", resImage);
        args.putString("title", title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_img, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMain);
        button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        tvLabel.setText(title);
        imageView.setImageResource(image);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Lista_Smartphone.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```